# looking for a word meaning 'make look bigger or make seem more important in effect or influence'

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm looking for a word or phrase verb meaning 'make look bigger or make seem more important than what they actually are in effect or influence'.
it isn't 'to exaggerate'. I learned a word for that but forgot it. it had a meaning similar to that.

Comment: Perhaps _inflate_ might fit the bill. It would be easier if you gave us an example sentence as I suspect the best word depends on context.

Comment: [*"A noble spirit **embiggens** the smallest man."*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcxsgZxqnEg) But [according to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embiggen#h1), that one (unlike, say, "cromulent") predates *The Simpsons*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Ah you are the one who suggested this question to close? lmao. I sure did search it on Thesaurus dictionary but as i said i learned a word that has such meaning but none of them wasn't matched. I did research by myself but couldn't find it so i decided to seek help here. i'm not that lazy as you think. when i ask something here i do it as last resort. I didn't add the part "I did research by myself but couldn't find it" to OP because it's a basic thing. appreciate you are here to help but that one is obnoxious to me.

Comment: @mdewey I initially thought of inflate and started searching its synonyms with inflate but there wasn't what I looked for, and I wasn't sure if it can be used in positive situations as well as negative. I want to use the word like when something makes the other(s) look bigger or seem more important in good way.

Comment: I think it has both positive and negative meanings. May I repeat though my comment that it would be easier if we saw the context you want to use it in?

Comment: @phen08 No, I didn't vote to close. I expect everyone to use a dictionary and a thesaurus. No hate.

Comment: @FeliniusRex You're 100% right. Everyone should use a dictionary and a thesaurus before asking questions here. I'm not a shameless person haha. I'll choose better words so that there will be no misunderstanding. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @mdewey I only remember the word's definition not the name of it(I saw it on thefreedictionary I don't know how I remember only the definition I found it very useful yet forgot the actual word) so I thought putting the definition in the post could provide some sort of context for it. Apologies. And for inflate, my dictionary's examples and the ones on the others show only negative situations. So I can use both I suppose? the context I can try coming up with is "that line of the actor makes him seem more important or embiggens the influence he has on the series."

Comment: I'm leaving this question open because we cannot reasonably expect askers to find words in a dictionary if they only have the definition

Answer (score 1):

If you google **exaggerate** the very first answer you will get under the heading "Dictionary" contains a section headed "Similar" under which you can see

> overstate, overemphasize, overstress, overestimate ...

and many more. Take your pick to suit your specific context.

If that's not good enough, try googling **exaggerate synonyms**.

Comment: Yeah i tried searching synonyms but none of them matched what i looked for. I saw those too but they're more like negative. I want to use it in positive way. thank you for the suggestion by the way.

Answer (score 1):

## Puff *object* up

To *puff something up*, *puff someone up* or *puff yourself up* mean to talk about someone or something and make them look better than they really are. It can mean more powerful or dangerous, or more attractive and desirable.

> I'm selling my junky old car online, so I have to **puff it up** in the ads. (more attractive, desirable)
>
> The boxer's manager **puffed him up** in the media before the fight to intimidate his opponent. (more powerful, dangerous)
>
> My buddy Drew is a great wingman because he knows how to convincingly **puff me up** to women I'm interested in. (more attractive, desirable)

To "puff yourself up" can also mean to push your chest out, or do other things to make yourself look physically bigger and more intimidating, but that's a different sense of the term.

**NOTE:** I grew up using this word as normal language --not even slang-- but I can't find any definitions of it in standard dictionaries nor even in the Urban Dictionary catch-all bin, so it might be just a local expression from where I grew up. So please wait for comments and up-votes before accepting.

Comment: In BrE I think the modern slang among young people is _to big it up_